# Switch the content of two WPF TextBoxes and ScrollToEnd()

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to switch the text of two WPF TextBoxes, set the caret to the end of each TextBox and scroll those caret positions into view (so that the last character of each TextBox is still visible).

This is a simple version of the Window:

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="aaabbbcccd" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="2" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="aaaaabbbbbcccccd" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Switch text" Width="70" Margin="4" Click="OnClick_button_switchText" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is the code-behind of the click event:

```
private void OnClick_button_switchText( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
     // Switch text
     string text1  = textBox1.Text;
     textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
     textBox2.Text = text1;

     // Scroll to last characters
     textBox1.ScrollToEnd();
     textBox2.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

Unfortunately, ScrollToEnd() does not work as expected: nothing happens. Therefore, I also tried several other possibilities - which also didn't do anything, until I started to set the focus:

```
private void OnClick_button_switchText( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    ...

    // 2nd try
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.CaretIndex = textBox1.Text.Length;
    textBox2.Focus();
    textBox2.CaretIndex = textBox2.Text.Length;

    // 3rd try
    textBox1.Focus();
    EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd.Execute( null, textBox1 );
    textBox2.Focus();
    EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd.Execute( null, textBox2 );

    // 4th try
    textBox1.Focus();
    Rect a_charIndexRect = textBox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex( textBox1.CaretIndex );
    textBox1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( a_charIndexRect.Right );
    textBox2.Focus();
    a_charIndexRect = textBox2.GetRectFromCharacterIndex( textBox2.CaretIndex );
    textBox2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( a_charIndexRect.Right );
}
```

If the focus was set right before the actual scroll-method it nearly worked (with the 2nd and 3rd possibility): textBox2 displays the text correctly, but textBox1 still does not scroll to the end - BUT it does set the caret to the end.
If you press tab to focus this control you'll notice that the cursor is at the end, but out of view.

So I thought this could be some kind of timing issue and tried to execute the corresponding scroll-method inside a "GotFocus" event of the TextBoxes, but without any success.

Is there any way to switch the text of two TextBoxes and still show the last characters?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Start using WPF, it will be fun they said"... If your idea of fun is to know exactly how WPF works behind the scene and then adhere to their design idea and never stray from it. You probably need to rebuild your app according to MVVM-standard in order to get this to work. On a more seriuos note though... programmatically changing stuff in WPF is IFFY, you might need to set keyboard focus on textbox as well, and then scroll. You might need to wait for x frames between doing stuff... WPF was never meant to make sense for ppl doing stuff programatically. "It wil lbe fun and awesome they said..."

Comment: Unfortunately, your question isn't entirely clear about what you expect to happen. But, your example doesn't look like a multiline text box. if you are expecting the `TextBox` view to scroll horizontally, then your expectations are incorrect. The `ScrollToEnd()` method only scrolls _vertically_ to the last line of the content. In fact, it intentionally will scroll horizontally to the _left_ (i.e. beginning) at the same time. That said, I _would_ expect `ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double.PositiveInfinity)` to work in that case. Please clarify what it is you are actually expecting to happen.

Comment: @DanielMesSer: yes, WPF makes some hard tasks really easy - but some easy tasks really hard...  I'll look into it and try to figure out a MVVM way to do it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: the question relates to the posted XAML code, so I want to scroll horizontally to the end of the TextBox like you assumed. Ok this explains why ScrollToEnd() fails completely.
Using
    ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity )
seems to work if I don't focus anything at all. As soon as a TextBox should be focused after that, the caret remains at the starting position to the left. So if you want a blinking caret at one of those TextBoxes after switching the text it will fail as well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: but combining this with the 2nd or 3rd possibility posted above works! I will post an answer for this, so that is clear for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries and a hint posted by Peter Duniho I figured out how to do it.
Note that this is still not a perfect solution, because it isn't a MVVM approach - but a working way to do it.
You have to use different methods if you want to focus one of those TextBoxes after you scrolled to the end:

```
private void OnClick_button_switchText( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
     // Switch text
     string text1  = textBox1.Text;
     textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
     textBox2.Text = text1;

     // Scroll to end - without focus
     textBox1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity );
     textBox2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity );

     // Scroll to end - and focus the first TextBox
     textBox1.Focus();
     EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd.Execute( null, textBox1 );
     textBox2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity );

     // Scroll to end - and focus the second TextBox
     textBox1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity );
     textBox2.Focus();
     EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd.Execute( null, textBox2 );
}
```

**Edit: here's my MVVM approach (I kept the existing focus)**

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Text1}" behaviors:TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior.ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior="True" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Text2}" behaviors:TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior.ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior="True" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Content="Switch text" Width="70" Margin="4" Command="{Binding CommandSwitchText}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using Behaviors;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace ViewModels
{
   class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
   {
      public MainWindowViewModel()
      {
         CommandSwitchText = new RelayCommand( SwitchText );
      }


      public RelayCommand CommandSwitchText
      {
         get;
         private set;
      }


      private void SwitchText()
      {
         TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior.IsActive = true;

         string textTemp = Text1;
         Text1 = Text2;
         Text2 = textTemp;

         TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior.IsActive = false;
      }


      private string _text1 = "aaabbbcccd";
      public string Text1
      {
         get
         {
            return _text1;
         }
         set
         {
            _text1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
         }
      }


      private string _text2 = "aaaaabbbbbcccccd";
      public string Text2
      {
         get
         {
            return _text2;
         }
         set
         {
            _text2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Behavior:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace Behaviors
{
   public static class TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior
   {
      private static bool _isActive = false;
      public static bool IsActive
      {
         get
         {
            return _isActive;
         }
         set
         {
            _isActive = value;
         }
      }




      public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior = 
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior",
                                              typeof( bool ),
                                              typeof( TextBoxScrollToEndBehavior ),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata( false, OnScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior ) );




      public static bool GetScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior( DependencyObject obj )
      {
         return (bool)obj.GetValue( ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior );
      }




      public static void SetScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior( DependencyObject obj, bool value )
      {
         obj.SetValue( ScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior, value );
      }




      private static void OnScrollToEndOnEnabledBehavior( object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
      {
         TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
         if( textBox != null )
         {
            bool isEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
            if( isEnabled )
            {
               textBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged_textBox;
            }
            else
            {
               textBox.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged_textBox;
            }
         }
      }




      static void OnTextChanged_textBox( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
      {
         TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
         if( null != textBox )
         {
            if( IsActive )
            {
               if( textBox.IsFocused )
               {
                  EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd.Execute( null, textBox );
               }
               else
               {
                  textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( double.PositiveInfinity );
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```